# ADB rejected shell command (getprop): closed

Tags: android-studio, adb

Using Android Studio and when trying to run a simple demonstration app the emulator I selected starts up but never renders the app. In the event log I see stuff like the following:

> 2:59 PM   Emulator: emulator: WARNING: Host CPU is missing the following
>   feature(s) required for x86 emulation: SSSE3
>
> 2:59 PM   Emulator: Hardware-accelerated emulation may not work
>   properly!
>
> 2:59 PM   Emulator: qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support
>   requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.ssse3 [bit 9]
>
> 2:59 PM   Emulator: qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support
>   requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.sse4.1 [bit 19]
>
> 2:59 PM   Emulator: qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support
>   requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.sse4.2 [bit 20]
>
> 2:59 PM   ADB rejected shell command (getprop): closed
>
> 2:59 PM   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0

- Tried restarting Android Studio
- Tried recreating the AVD image
- Tried killing and restarting adb

Running Ubuntu 18.04 with Android Studio 3.4

I expected that the emulator would start up and render the app created so far. I'm following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dFlPARW5IX8 and at about 21:22.
It says to press play and the emulator should start and show the app we have coded so far. I never see this.

Comment: Not sure why this is listed as closed. It's not closed. I just asked the question!

Comment: I could resolve this issue by updating the android studio via Help menu -> check for updates. After the update is complete, you'll be prompted to import config. But import nothing and continue with that fresh re-installation.

Comment: I did update and not resolved. I have been dealing with this error only when I`m trying my app using in real mobile.  The same mobile used to be OK in the same notebook android studio.  It is still OK for now in same notebook for virtual device. The same mobile is OK in other notebook android studio.